# Restrict duplicate contact role on opportunity

Tags: apex

Is there anyway to restrict assigning same contact with different roles on opportunity?

Ex: I have "Test opportunity" and under contact roles i have contact "Joseph" that's been assigned twice as primary with different roles. I just want to know if there is any possibility to restrict assigning same contact again if it already exists under contact role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpportunityContactRole` can not have a trigger (something oft-requested/seen here in SFSE)

The best workaround for this is to use what is called a 'View trigger' on Opportunity detail page.

- Create a small Opportunity Controller Extension class associated with a small VF page that ..
- Reads the list of child OCRs and if there's a duplicate role...
- Uses `apex:pageMessages` to display the error in the VF page included as an element of the Opportunity Detail page

Thus, while the detection of duplicates doesn't happen on the screen where OCRs are defined/edited, when user hits Save, the Opportunity Detail page is shown and you can show the error then. This is an 'advisory' error and depending on how insistent you make it, the user may or may not take corrective action.

Comment: You could even have that extension delete the offending records, perhaps.